# ROS: Node is subscribed to a topic but not receiving the message

Tags: arduino, ros

My hardware is Romi32U4.
My serial node is a subscriber to cmd_vel topic and there's a method converts Twist to the left and right speeds. I can move the robot by manually publish Twist message.

Now, I want to use turtlebot3_teleop to publish Twist messages. I've followed e-manual tutorial to setup remote PC. According to rqt_graph, teleop is publishing to cmd_vel and serial node is subscribing to cmd_vel too. When I echo cmd_vel, I can get the values. However, serial node is not responding. The call back function is not called. I don't know why. The serial node should execute call back function when it gets a Twist message, which it is published by teleop.

This is my class:

```
#define USE_USBCON
#include <Romi32U4.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>

Romi32U4Motors motors;

ros::NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware, 6, 6, 150, 150> nh;
std_msgs::Float32 left_msg;
ros::Publisher left_vel_pub("chatter", &left_msg);

std_msgs::Float32 right_msg;
ros::Publisher right_vel_pub("chatter", &right_msg);


//call back
void msgTwist(const geometry_msgs::Twist& twist_msg){
  float wheel_dist = 13;

  float linear_vel = twist_msg.linear.x * 2000;
  float angle_vel = twist_msg.angular.z * 15; 

  float right_sp = (angle_vel*wheel_dist)/2 + linear_vel;
  float left_sp = linear_vel*2 - right_sp;

  left_msg.data = left_sp;
  left_vel_pub.publish( &left_msg );

  right_msg.data = right_sp;
  right_vel_pub.publish( &right_msg );

  motors.setSpeeds(left_sp, right_sp)
}

ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> sub("cmd_vel", &msgTwist);

void setup() {
  nh.initNode();  
  nh.advertise(left_vel_pub);
  nh.advertise(right_vel_pub);
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop() {
  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

Comment: Do you subscribe your callback to the topic? Do you call the spinner? Please post a complete minimal working example.

Comment: @Tik0 Just updated. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. The problem is the delay in the callback function. turtlebot3_teleop keeps sending messages. The delay slows down the speed of receiving the message and eventually crashed the serial node. Simply delete the delay will fix the problem.